# How can I amplify an analog DC voltage signal?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, analog, dc, dc-dc-converter

I have a 24 VDC liquid sensor that outputs 0.6 - 1.6 VDC depending on the quantity of liquid on a substrate.

How can this be amplified to ~1.0 - 10 VDC?

Comment: Also related: [Can this analog voltage be scaled and shifted to the new range using op amps with only ±12V power supplies?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/609017/101852)

Comment: A straightforward gain of 6.25 will give you 3.75 to 10V. If you need more like 1~10V you will need a reference to subtract an offset. What kind of accuracy requirements are there?

Answer (score 1):

Subtract 0.6V and scale by 9 and add 1V.

**Or in math terms:**

*VOut = (VIn - 0.6V)x9 + 1V-> Vout [1;10]V with Vin [0,6;1,6]V*

**Or in circuit terms:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUkVFR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**(1) Substraction:**

Please see [Subtractor using Op Amp or Difference Amplifier Circuit](https://www.eeeguide.com/subtractor-using-op-amp-or-difference-amplifier-circuit/)

**(2) Multiplier:**

Please see [Non Inverting Operational Amplifier](https://www.eeeguide.com/non-inverting-operational-amplifier/)

**(3) Ready-To-Use:**

But, others have alread solved these problems.

For reference (**not a recommendation**) see: [Phoenix contact analog components for automation use](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/de-de/produkte/trennverstaerker-und-messumformer)

Or in particular (**not a recommendation**) see: [Configureable analog amplifier with galvanic isolation](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/de-de/produkte/trennverstaerker-macx-mcr-ui-ui-nc-2811446) in its [0;2]->[0;10]V configuration. You can remove the 0.6V DC-Bias in your SPS/Measurement device.

**(4) Working circuit:**

As a working circuit, i came up with this *complex* solution (Note: I'm not a analog expert!)

[image]

This circuit produces the following output: *VIn [0,6:1,6]V -> [1;10]V*

[image]

**First:** A DC-Offset of -0.6V is added to Vin (Blue line). Note: The output is inverted also! This produces V_Add_1 (Green line). For *Vin [0,6;1,6]V -> [0;-1]V*

**Then:** The V_Add_1 is scaled *9 to produce V_Mul_1 (Red line). For *V_Add_1 [0;-1]V -> [0;-9]V*.

**Finally:** A DC-Offset of -1V is added to V_Mul_1. Note: The output is inverted also! This produces VOut (Blueish color). For *V_Mul_1 [0;-9]V -> [1;10]V with correct phase*

Comment: I didn’t downvote you, but using a multiplier to get a fixed gain is not a good approach at all.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Agreed - heat of the moment. Did a edit.

Comment: Incorrect output voltage range.

Comment: @AnalogKid Well, the ~ in the question leaves room for adaptation...don't you think?

Comment: The word is subtraction, not substraction.

Comment: A better assumption would be that if the OP wanted the low end of the output voltage range to be 0 V, he would have said so.  My guess is that the OP wants the bottom end of the output range to be **not** 0 V, as in something above 0 V, for a reason.  In analog signal processing, there is a big difference between 0 V and anything-other-than-0 V.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this circuit with a 24 V supply already you have.

[image]